# Adding text to a file is displayed in one long line

Tags: c#, .net, file

I am having an issue where when I write text to a second file, it display fine in **wordpad** where it includes the `linebreaks`, but in **notepad** all the text for `copyText` and `richTextBox1.Text` appear in one really long line.

How can I fix this? If somebody can include a code snippet with my code then it will be much appreciated as I can see what you have done and changed and I can keep it for reference for futr use.

My code is below where I take text from a text file (`Testfile.txt`) and insert it into `richTextBox1`, then when I click on button, text is copied to `richText Box2` and is written in second file (`_Parsed.txt`). 
I did a message box on text line and it displays text all without line break. I'm not sure if that is issue but I do need help as deadline is tomorrow and this is only thing I need to sort out and I'm done.

```
string Chosen_File = "C:\\_Testfile.txt";
string Second_File = "C:\\_Parsed.txt";
string wholeText = "";

private void mnuOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        //Add data from text file to rich text box
        richTextBox1.LoadFile(Chosen_File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

        //Read lines of text in text file                
        string textLine = "";

        StreamReader txtReader;
        txtReader = new StreamReader(Chosen_File);

        do {
            textLine = textLine + txtReader.ReadLine() + " ";
        }

        //Read line until there is no more characters
        while (txtReader.Peek() != -1);

        richTextBox1.Text = textLine;

        txtReader.Close();
    }

}

private void Write(string file, string text) {

    //Check to see if _Parsed File exists

        //Write to _Parsed text file
        using(StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(file)) {
            objWriter.Write(text);
            objWriter.Close();
    } 

}

private void newSummaryMethod(string copyText) {

    //Write into richTextBox2 all relevant text
    copyText = richTextBox1.Text;
    wholeText = richTextBox1.Text + copyText
    Write(Second_File, wholeText);
}


private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        newSummaryMethod(copyText);
}
```

Comment: I think word wrap option is turned on in your wordpad program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are never adding a new line to the file in your code. you are using `objWriter.Write(text);` which does not generate a new line.

you can use `objWriter.WriteLine(text);` instead and it will automatically add new line character at the end.

I think the difference in viewing the file is because the "word wrap" option is turned on in "wordpad" and it causes to break a long line into multiple line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably with the line breaks in your text file(s).
TextBoxes expect `\r\n` sequence as an indication of the end-of-line, and your text files may contain only the `\n`.
Try to make this change to your code:

```
 do {
        textLine = textLine + txtReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
    }

    //Read line until there is no more characters
    while (txtReader.Peek() != -1);
```